# Dynamically image binding vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to do the same as here but instead I want to use images.sample as parameter e.g `props`:`['images.sample']`,

```
<template>
<img :src="images.sample">
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            images: {
                sample: require('./assets/static/images/sample.jpg')
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where's the child component ? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: this is supposed to be the child component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child component should be like :

```
<template>
<img :src="url">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name:'child-img',
   props:['url'],
    data() {
        return {

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

the parent component should have this content :

```
<template>
<child-img :url="images.sample"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            images: {
                sample: require('./assets/static/images/sample.jpg')
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That should work, however, I have another question, I'm using <router-link :to"{path: '/', query:{name:'item',...}}" how can I use that here ?

Comment: you could post another question with more details and i hope i could help you

Comment: here you go : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796701/pass-an-image-as-prop-in-a-router-link-tag