# Pass an image as prop in a router-link tag

Tags: vue.js

How can I pass an image as `prop` in a vue-router tag ?
I have :

```
 <router-link :to="{path: '/details', query: { 
            name: 'item', 
            //...
          }}">
 </routerlink
```

while in my "details" component I have :

```
<template>
<img :src="url">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name:'child-img',
   props:['url'],
    data() {
        return {

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need pass a prop with your router tag? What is your use case?

Comment: I have a page that contains a list of items, and when I press on a specific item, it redirects me to another component that contains some text and an image, I want to change that image dynamically from my <router-link> tag.

Answer (score 0):

So it's a case of passing props to your route which you have to set up in your router.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/details/:url', component: Details, props: true },
    // ...
  ]
})
```

then when you use your route:

```
<router-link to="`/details/${url}`">Details</router-link>
```

In the above url is the dynamic element you would be passing to it. If it comes from a v-for loop it would be item.url or whatever you are v-for ing.

**OR** if you name your route you can pass a param like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/details/:url', name: 'Details', component: Details, props: true },
    // ...
  ]
})
```

then use it like this:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Details', params: { url } }">
   Details
</router-link>
```

You can read more [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components)