# Vue.js Dynamic Image paths after compiling/runtime

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a problem setting dynamic image paths with Vue.js. I am using the Vue-Cli to build the project.

I believe the issue is caused because I am referencing image paths dynamically *after* runtime. Normally it seems the references to my ./assets/ folder are converted into ./img/ after runtime. Since I am changing the url dynamically after load the paths don't appear to work/load. Country is initially set via a store getters but is then v-modeled from a language select dropdown, where the values correspond the the url suffix.

```
    <div id="flag-container" :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${src})` }"></div>

    computed: {
            src(){
                return `./assets/flags/flag-${this.country}.png`;
            }
        },

    data() {
        return {
            country: this.$store.getters.language
        }
    }
```

Inspector shows url change is implemented.

Any recommendation on the best solution for this?

Comment: In devtools did you inspect the network tab? Are the images linked properly? Do they exist on the server? __Inspector shows url change is implemented.__ so when you inspect the dom, you can see that `url()` is correctly set when you change country?

Comment: Can you add example of rendered `<div id="flag-container" ...>`

Comment: <div id="flag-container" style="background-image: url("./assets/flags/flag-ru-RU.png");"></div>

Yes, I see the change implemented in the HTML but get no render of the image.

Comment: please check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950105/how-do-i-bind-a-src-for-an-image-in-the-child-component/53952017#53952017) or this [`one`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794737/dynamically-image-binding-vue/53794830#53794830)

Comment: As I said in comment above, use browser devtools to inspect network traffic. Are images loaded? is there a 404 (not found) for image requests?

Comment: oh, I just noticed. DO NOT set `data()` `country` to `this.$store.getters.language`. Create `computed: { country() { return this.$store.getters.language } }`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I understand about requiring individual images but need a way to require an entire directory... there will be about 50+ images.

Comment: @MichaelPaccione not only individual images, just add `require`, check this webpack docs section https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression

Comment: Thanks Max your link helped me figure this out!

Answer (score 2):

Using `webpack` [require context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#context-module-api) and `beforeMount`, I was able to store the images in base64 format inside an object. I stored the object and accessed it with a dynamic key. Thanks Max for leading me to the right documentation.

```js
export default {
  beforeMount() {
    var that = this;
    function importAll(r) {
      r.keys().forEach((key) => (that.imgCache[key] = r(key)));
    }

    importAll(require.context("../assets/flags/", true, /\.png$/));
  },
  computed: {
    src() {
      var key = `./flag-${this.country}.png`,
        url = this.imgCache[key];

      return url;
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
data() {
    return {
        country: this.$store.getters.language
    }
}
```

as it will stop being reactive to store changes. Use computed property

```
<div id="flag-container" :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${src})` }"></div>

computed: {
    src(){
        return `./assets/flags/flag-${this.country}.png`;
    },
    country() {
        return this.$store.getters.language
    }
},
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying with your data flow... having the store be the master source and updating from that. What I have on this component instead is local data values that are v-modeled and then @change I update the store. So it is not from what I can see the issue as I am seeing the URL change when i change my select.