# how to add correctly an image in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to have the image be shown in my project; however, I wasn't able to work it out.

I did search for a solution, and I tried it but it didn't work out for me.

What could be the solution here? Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is the html part:

```html
    <template>
            <div id="app">
            <div class="productListing">
                <div class="box effect1" :key="product.id" v-for="product in ProductFilter.slice(0,3)">
                    <h1>{{product.title}}</h1>
                    <img :src="product.img" alt="dd">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            </template>
    vue js part 
    <script>
    export default {
      data: function () {
          return {
              userFilterKey: 'all',
      products:[
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Google Pixel - Black",
        price: 10,
        company: "GOOGLE",
    status : "TopSell",
    img: "../../bg.jpeg"

      }

    ],
          }

      },
      computed: {
        ProductFilter() {
            return this[this.userFilterKey]
        },
        all() {
          return this.products
        },
        TopSell() {
          return this.products.filter((product) => product.status === "TopSell")
        },
        highRated() {
          return this.products.filter((product) => product.status === "HighRated")
        },
      }
    }
    // @ is an alias to /src
    </script>
```

Thanks again in advance for your help.

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794737/dynamically-image-binding-vue/53794830#53794830)

Comment: its the same logic i have in my code i guess its just u had parent element and child element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the image path you provided is correct, use the `require` function instead.

```
products: [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Google Pixel - Black",
    price: 10,
    company: "GOOGLE",
    status : "TopSell",
    img: require("../../bg.jpeg")
  }
],
```